# sendmail on ubuntu not working correctly

Tags: ubuntu, php, email-server, sendmail

I am in the process of setting up a new server which runs Ubuntu on a LAMP stack.

I have installed sendmail but it doesnt seem to work.

This is my output in the error log:

```
Apr 16 13:46:51 ip-10-33-164-173 sm-mta[12939]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mail.imagine-publishing.co.uk., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Apr 16 13:46:51 ip-10-33-164-173 sm-mta[12939]: r3GDkeJG012937: to=<web@imagine-publishing.co.uk>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-33-164-173.eu-west-1.compute.internal> (33/33), delay=00:00:11, xdelay=00:00:11, mailer=esmtp, pri=120967, relay=mail.imagine-publishing.co.uk. [86.28.80.249], dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error
Apr 16 13:46:51 ip-10-33-164-173 sm-mta[12939]: r3GDkeJG012937: r3GDkpJG012939: DSN: Data format error
Apr 16 13:46:51 ip-10-33-164-173 sm-mta[12939]: r3GDkpJG012939: to=<www-data@ip-10-33-164-173.eu-west-1.compute.internal>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

That error was taken from /var/mail/www-data
`(reason: 553 5.1.8 Sender address <www-data@ip-10-33-164-173.eu-west-1.compute.internal> domain does not exist)`

Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to server admin stuff so any help would be appriciated!

Comment: 1) Could you post bounce email generated and send to www-data? It may contain more hints. 2) Can you send email to other domains successfully?

Comment: (reason: 553 5.1.8 Sender address <www-data@ip-10-33-164-173.eu-west-1.compute.internal> domain does not exist)

Comment: That error was taken from /var/mail/www-data

Comment: Do your have a public IP address?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to use this in the config files somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sendmail uses invalid "this host email name". It is used by default as domain in sender addresses. Other mail server reject such sender address (domain without DNS records).

Set **both** *envelope sender* and *header sender* addresses in you php configuration/script. Set them to user@valid.domain.
http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Your sendmail should be fixed too.
Change "this host email name" to name with `A` or `MX` DNS record:
* change hostname as reported by `hostname --fqdn`
*OR*
* change it for sendmail only https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/whoami.html

Comment: where do I need to change "this host email name"? What file needs changing?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-04